# How to create a faked Response (Python Library "requests")

Tags: python-requests

In a unittest I would like to create a fake Response from the requests library.

I tried this:

```
response=requests.Response()
response.content='asf'
```

I get this exception:

```
    response.content='asf'
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

How to create a fake requests response?

With "fake" I mean a Response instance but without creating any http traffic.

Comment: What do you mean 'fake' ? You want to write a new `response` class ?

Comment: @t.m.adam With "fake" I mean a Response instance but without creating any http traffic. I added this to the question. Does this answer your question?

Comment: You mean something like [prepared-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) , yes ?

Comment: Are you doing this in a unit-testing context?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes :-)  `self.assertEqual('unittest', this_question.split()[2])`

Comment: Then why not just using `unittest.mock`? What does the code-under-test look like?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the two code lines from the question are from a method which I use to create fake Response. I use mocking to call this method. But it fails since I can't set the response.content attribute.

Comment: @guettli: but `requests.Response` is not a mock. If I saw the code under test it'd be trivial to produce a `unittest.mock` mock for your code. `requests-mock` gives you basically the same thing with some extra convenience methods (although that library re-invents the mocking wheel to a large extent).

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you really need more code from me? All I want is an instance of `requests.Response` which has content `asf`.

Comment: @guettli: and I'm telling you that that's an X-Y problem. You can solve the issue much better with an appropriate mock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [requests-mock](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mocker.html) package to do this. Example from the docs:

```
>>> @requests_mock.Mocker()
... def test_function(m):
...     m.get('http://test.com', text='resp')
...     return requests.get('http://test.com').text
...
>>> test_function()
'resp'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint. I was not aware of this library. Thank you.

Comment: @guettli: don't confuse *asking for recommendations*, and answering a question with *that's best solved with*.